# What does mean standard transactions , standard non transactions and custom records in Netsuite API?

Tags: php, netsuite, suitescript

In following link listed out unit cost associated with API.

https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10365

For **nlapiDeleteRecord** and **nlapiSubmitRecord** Shown unit cost as below,

> When used on standard transactions: 20
>
> When used on standard non-transactions: 10
>
> When used on custom records: 4

What does it mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why ask here when this could be easily answered by the netsuite team if you spoke to them directly?

Comment: This will be helpful. https://system.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3350760.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions: salesorders, invoices, etc.... Found under transactions menu

Non-Transactions: customers, contacts, etc...

Custom Records: Records that are not native. These record types start with "cust". They are found under customization>Record Types

Comment: Thanks @AdolfoGarza

Answer (score 1):

General speaking:

Standard Transactions: All record types available as a 'type' filter on a new `Transaction` search.  All 'Transactions' have potential GL impact.

Standard Non-Transactions: All other native records. (ie: CRM records [entity, case, project, ...], item records, etc)

Custom Records: Anything created in `Customization->List, Records, Fields->Record Types`  These will all have a record id prefixed with `customrecord_`

When in doubt, verify! There are several ways you might do this, but here's a really basic one for debug console or client script usage, gives you the before and after usage after loading the current record:

```
console.log(nlapiGetContext().getRemainingUsage());

var test = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(),nlapiGetRecordId());

console.log(nlapiGetContext().getRemainingUsage());
```

Comment: Thanks @SheaBrennan